# Response for preflight is invalid (redirect) using Asp.Net Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm developing a website which uses AngularJS in the frontend and ASP.NET web API in the backend. I'm trying to configure external logins(Facebook) for my site. I have already enabled Cors on the API. The order of API calls are:

1. API call to 
   `api/Account/ExternalLogins?returnUrl=%2F&generateState=true` 
   to get a list of external login providers.
2. This returns
   `[{"name":"Facebook",
   "url":"/api/Account/ExternalLogin?provider=Facebook&response_type=token&client_id=self&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A15359%2F&state=xxxxxxxxxx",
   "state":"xxxxxxxxxx"}]`
3. Now I send a GET request to url returned earlier. This triggers a preflight request to `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxx&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44327%2Fsignin-facebook&scope=manage_pages&state=xxxxxxx` which gives error. This is never redirected to Facebook Login Page.

Both the request and response headers for `/api/Account/ExternalLogin?provider=Facebook&response_type=token&client_id=self&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A15359%2F&state=xxxxxxxxxx`  contains `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`

But for the preflight request `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxx&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44327%2Fsignin-facebook&scope=manage_pages&state=xxxxxxx` Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is missing.

The code snippets are mentioned below.

app.js

```
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = true;
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Method'] = 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS';
```

Start.Auth.cs

```
       // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        // Configure the sign in cookie
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });

        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
        PublicClientId = "self";
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),

            // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
            //Provider = new AuthorizationServerProvider()
        };

        // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);

        // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

        // Enables the application to remember the second login verification factor such as phone or email.
        // Once you check this option, your second step of verification during the login process will be remembered on the device where you logged in from.
        // This is similar to the RememberMe option when you log in.
        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);



        var facebookOptions = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AppId = "xxxxxxxxx",
            AppSecret = "xxxxxxxxx",
            BackchannelHttpHandler = new FacebookBackChannelHandler(),

            Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider()
            {
                OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
                {
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("FacebookAccessToken", context.AccessToken));
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }

            },
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie,
            SendAppSecretProof = true
        };

        facebookOptions.Scope.Add(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Facebook_Scope"]);
        facebookOptions.AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive;
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions);
```

AccountController

```
[Authorize]
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
[RoutePrefix("api/Account")]
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    private const string LocalLoginProvider = "Local";
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    public AccountController()
    {
    }

    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager,
        ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> accessTokenFormat)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        AccessTokenFormat = accessTokenFormat;
    }

    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }

    public ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> AccessTokenFormat { get; private set; }

    // GET api/Account/UserInfo
    [HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer)]
    [Route("UserInfo")]
    public UserInfoViewModel GetUserInfo()
    {
        ExternalLoginData externalLogin = ExternalLoginData.FromIdentity(User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity);

        return new UserInfoViewModel
        {
            Email = User.Identity.GetUserName(),
            HasRegistered = externalLogin == null,
            LoginProvider = externalLogin != null ? externalLogin.LoginProvider : null
        };
    }

    // POST api/Account/Logout
    [Route("Logout")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IHttpActionResult Logout()
    {
        Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        return Ok();
    }


    // POST api/Account/AddExternalLogin
    [Route("AddExternalLogin")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> AddExternalLogin(AddExternalLoginBindingModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        AuthenticationTicket ticket = AccessTokenFormat.Unprotect(model.ExternalAccessToken);

        if (ticket == null || ticket.Identity == null || (ticket.Properties != null
            && ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc.HasValue
            && ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc.Value < DateTimeOffset.UtcNow))
        {
            return BadRequest("External login failure.");
        }

        ExternalLoginData externalData = ExternalLoginData.FromIdentity(ticket.Identity);

        if (externalData == null)
        {
            return BadRequest("The external login is already associated with an account.");
        }

        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(),
            new UserLoginInfo(externalData.LoginProvider, externalData.ProviderKey));

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return GetErrorResult(result);
        }

        return Ok();
    }

    // GET api/Account/ExternalLogin
    [OverrideAuthentication]
    [HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie)]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("ExternalLogin", Name = "ExternalLogin")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetExternalLogin(string provider, string error = null)
    {
        if (error != null)
        {
            return Redirect(Url.Content("~/") + "#error=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(error));
        }

        if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return new ChallengeResult(provider, this);
        }

        ExternalLoginData externalLogin = ExternalLoginData.FromIdentity(User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity);

        if (externalLogin == null)
        {
            return InternalServerError();
        }

        if (externalLogin.LoginProvider != provider)
        {
            Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            return new ChallengeResult(provider, this);
        }

        ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindAsync(new UserLoginInfo(externalLogin.LoginProvider,
            externalLogin.ProviderKey));

        bool hasRegistered = user != null;

        if (hasRegistered)
        {
            Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager,
               OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            ClaimsIdentity cookieIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager,
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            AuthenticationProperties properties = ApplicationOAuthProvider.CreateProperties(user.UserName);
            Authentication.SignIn(properties, oAuthIdentity, cookieIdentity);
        }
        else
        {
            IEnumerable<Claim> claims = externalLogin.GetClaims();
            ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            Authentication.SignIn(identity);
        }

        return Ok();
    }

    // GET api/Account/ExternalLogins?returnUrl=%2F&generateState=true
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("ExternalLogins")]
    public IEnumerable<ExternalLoginViewModel> GetExternalLogins(string returnUrl, bool generateState = false)
    {
        IEnumerable<AuthenticationDescription> descriptions = Authentication.GetExternalAuthenticationTypes();
        List<ExternalLoginViewModel> logins = new List<ExternalLoginViewModel>();

        string state;

        if (generateState)
        {
            const int strengthInBits = 256;
            state = RandomOAuthStateGenerator.Generate(strengthInBits);
        }
        else
        {
            state = null;
        }

        foreach (AuthenticationDescription description in descriptions)
        {
            ExternalLoginViewModel login = new ExternalLoginViewModel
            {
                Name = description.Caption,
                Url = Url.Route("ExternalLogin", new
                {
                    provider = description.AuthenticationType,
                    response_type = "token",
                    client_id = Startup.PublicClientId,
                    redirect_uri = new Uri(Request.RequestUri, returnUrl).AbsoluteUri,
                    state = state
                }),
                State = state
            };
            logins.Add(login);
        }

        return logins;
    }

    // POST api/Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("Register")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };

        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return GetErrorResult(result);
        }

        return Ok();
    }

    // POST api/Account/RegisterExternal
    [OverrideAuthentication]
    [HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer)]
    [Route("RegisterExternal")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> RegisterExternal(RegisterExternalBindingModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var info = await Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (info == null)
        {
            return InternalServerError();
        }

        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };

        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return GetErrorResult(result);
        }

        result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return GetErrorResult(result);
        }
        return Ok();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && _userManager != null)
        {
            _userManager.Dispose();
            _userManager = null;
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

}
```

I know this is achievable using MVC Account Controller. I'm looking for a way to do this entirely using web api with no dependency on MVC.

Thanks!